# Ursprung der Beleidigung als Schwein/Sau?

Tags: etymology, insult

Ich versuche rauszufinden was der historische und sprachliche Ursprung der abwertenden Bezeichnung von Menschen als "Schwein" oder "Sau" ist. Mir ist dabei nicht klar, ob der Ursprung tatsächlich im Deutschen liegt, oder sogar germanischen Sprachen zeitlich vorangeht.

Insbesondere die Popularisierung im Nationalsozialismus als antisemitische Abwertung hat mich auf die (ebenfalls ausschließlich antisemitische) "Judensau" gebracht, die auf das 11.-13. Jahrhundert datiert zu sein scheint. Diese Begrifflichkeit scheint als Beleidigung enstanden zu sein, da jüdischer Glauben u. Kultur Schweine als unkoscher versteht.

Das legt für mich die Vermutung nahe, dass der Versuch Menschen durch Bezeichnung als Schwein herabzuwerten, selbst wenn es die Begrifflichkeit der "Judensau" prädatiert, ohnehin antisemitische Wurzeln haben könnte. Kann diese Vermutung aber nicht belegen oder falsifizieren.

Gibt es dazu etymologische Forschung?

*(Edit)* Hiermit stehen folgende Aspekte in Zusammenhang: Wann taucht "Schwein" im Deutschen erstmals als Beleidigung auf? Welche (möglichen) Bedeutungsveränderungen macht "Schwein" im Deutschen durch? Wie ist der Zusammenhang des deutschen Begriffs mit Antisemitismus im deutschsprachigen Raum? Gibt es bspw. eine Häufung der Beleidigung zur Zeit des Nationalsozialismus?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97940/discussion-on-question-by-bitmask-ursprung-der-beleidigung-als-schwein-sau).

Comment: @Takkat Thanks: Could you help me and describe how to move a discussion to chat? I always see that discussions are becoming too long and would like to move them to chat, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Verschieben können nur Moderatoren, aber jeder kann ab 100 Reputationspunkten einen eigenen [Chat-Raum eröffnen](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms). Bequemer wäre es allerdings, längere Diskussionen einfach in unserem [chat] zu führen, der leider viel zu wenig benutzt wird.

Comment: Ich finde es jedesmal unbefriedigend, wenn Kommentar-Schlangen in eine separate Chat-Abteilung ausgewiesen werden. Die Kommentare sind entstanden als Teil der Bemühung, die Frage zu beantworten. Sie gehören direkt zur Frage. Abgenabelt von ihr sind sie nicht mehr interessant, und sie werden meiner Erfahrung nach dort auch nicht gelesen. - Speziell bei der vorliegenden Frage kreisten die Kommentare darum, ob die Behauptung, die in der Frage steckt (dass nämlich die Beleidigungsform "Sau" genuin antisemitisch sei), überhaupt haltbar ist. Das ist wesentlich für die Beantwortung der Frage.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage zur etymologischen Forschung kann ich leider nicht beantworten. Ich will mich daher eher an einer psychologischen/anthropologischen Betrachtung versuchen, und dabei gedanklich so weit wie möglich in der Zeit zurückgehen.

Ich lehne mich sicher nicht sehr weit aus dem Fenster, wenn ich behaupte, dass die Dominanzbeziehung zwischen Mensch (als Jäger) und Schwein oder irgendeinem anderem Tier (als Beute) mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit weiter in der Zeit zurückreicht, als die Entwicklung der Sprache. Es ist wohl eher unwahrscheinlich, dass zu jenen Zeiten mangels Sprache ein Mensch einem anderen mimische oder gestische Signale vermitteln konnte, die jenen empfinden lassen sollten, dass er ein bestimmtes nicht-menschliches Beutetier sei. Und selbst wenn eine solche nichtsprachliche Äußerung möglich gewesen wäre, wäre es für den "Beleidiger" eine viel effizientere Kommunikation gewesen, eine herkömmliche Drohgebärde zu zeigen, wie etwa die Zähne zu zeigen, durch starke Annäherung die Komfortzone des anderen zu verletzen, oder zu brüllen, etc.

Man darf also wohl annehmen, dass es mindestens irgendeiner sprachlichen Symbolik bedurfte, um jemanden als nicht-menschliches Beutetier zu bedrohen und damit vor anderen Menschen in der Rangordnung herabzustufen - also letztendlich zu beleidigen.

Die Frage die sich dann stellt ist: **ist es plausibel anzunehmen, dass Menschen - sobald die sprachlichen Mittel dazu erst einmal zur Verfügung standen - NICHT von der naheliegenden Möglichkeit Gebrauch gemacht haben, andere Menschen durch Vergleich mit einem Beutetier zu bedrohen und herabzuwürdigen.**

Da Menschen (zumindest nach meiner Erfahrung und Kenntnis heutiger Menschen) naturgemäß spielerisch expansiv mit den Möglichkeiten der Manipulation umgehen, erscheint es viel plausibler (getreu [Ockham's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)), dass die ersten sprachlich befähigten Menschen bewusst nach Möglichkeiten gesucht haben, die Aufgaben, die ihr Leben vorher bestimmt haben - zum Beispiel die Bedrohung und Dominierung ihrer Sozialgenossen - auf einfachere Weise mittels Sprache zu erreichen. Und je elementarer und alltäglicher die Aufgaben und Erkenntnissubjekte, desto schneller dürfte dies in der Sprache Niederschlag gefunden haben. Essen, Trinken, Tiere, Pflanzen, Aushandeln der sozialen Rangordnung kam sicher vor Gemütlichkeit bei der Einrichtung der Höhle oder der Pflege der Haare und Fußnägel.

Auf Grundlage dieser Argumentation erscheint es nahezu zwangsläufig, dass Beleidigungen durch Vergleiche mit Beutetieren (z.B. des Schweins) nicht nur bis in die frühesten Anfänge der Sprachkultur zurückreichen, sondern gerade damals viel zwangloser entstanden sind, als wir uns das heute vorstellen können. Heute sind wir vielleicht beschämt, wenn jemand als Schwein bezeichnet wird, ganz einfach weil unsere heutige Welt vergleichsweise aggressionsarm ist. Damals war soziales Gerangel ganz alltäglich, und ob das nun durch undifferenziertes Anbrüllen oder durch den Ausruf "Schwein" geschah, war kein wirklicher emotionaler Unterschied für die Beteiligten.

Als einen ersten Ansatz zu empirischem Beleg möchte ich anführen, dass es zum Beispiel in der Bibel, Matthäus 7,6 heißt:

> "Ihr sollt das Heilige nicht den Hunden geben und eure Perlen sollt
>   ihr nicht vor die Säue werfen, damit die sie nicht zertreten mit ihren
>   Füßen und sich umwenden und euch zerreißen."

Tiere (Hunde als bedrohliche Fressfeinde, Schweine als dumme Beutetiere, die alles was nicht ihrer Mästung dient, verschmähen) werden hier ganz klar zur Beleidigung/Herabwürdigung von Menschen mit bestimmten Eigenschaften missbraucht. Ironischerweise geschieht das unter dem Vorwand, die Kultur/Religion zu schützen.

Es fällt sicher nicht schwer, antik-römische, antik-griechische oder babylonische Zitate/Quellen zu finden, in denen Mensch-Tier-Vergleiche mit eindeutiger Absicht angestellt werden, zu finden. Wie weit die Quellen germanischer Schrift/Sprache zurückreichen weiß ich nicht.

Im übrigen gibt es auch genügend Vergleiche von Menschen mit vermeintlich mächtigen Tieren (Löwen, Tigern, Wölfen, Hirschen,...), welche als Lobpreisung (oder als Zeichen der eigenen ranglichen Unterordnung) verwendet werden.

Comment: Wenn du so weit zurückgehst, dass das Schwein eindeutiges Beutetier ist, dann hat die Erklärung den Haken, dass damals alle wussten, dass Wildschweine recht intelligent und ganz und gar keine einfachen Beutetiere sind...

Comment: Die Jäger als Spezialisten wussten das sicher. Wahrscheinlich haben sie die Wildschweine sogar verehrt. Wie wahrscheinlich ist es, dass souveräne Jäger es nötig hatten, andere einzuschüchtern. Das waren vermutlich eher politisch motivierte Individuen, die sich weniger über Produktivität als über die Vermeidung derselben definiert haben. Ist natürlich nicht ganz ernst gemeint...

Comment: Die Prämisse ist nicht haltbar, zumindest insofern der moderne Mensch erst durch Sprache geworden ist; Körpersprache zählt als Sprache. Ohne die wäre gemeinsame Jagd unmöglich. Da Kannibalismus weitgehend tabu ist, ist der Vergleich mit einem Beutetier aus heutiger Sicht wenig plausibel und die Annahme einer ungebrochenen Tradition aus der Jagd sehr weit hergeholt--wenngleich bspw. *Schlachten wie ein Schwein*, zumindest die Gewalt im Kern hat und *schreien [wie ein Schwein] am Spieß*  das Tabu eher kaschiert--da Tiernamen in Beleidigung nunmehr auf Dreck und Dummheit anspielen. ...

Comment: ... Das Schwein wurde recht spät domestiziert (gemein Indo-Europäische Namen fehlen), insofern könnte *Schwein* auch auf etwas schwer zu beherschendes wie die *wilde Sau* oder eben etwas wertloses anspielen. Die Beleidigung gegenüber der Kultur, die das Schwein tabuisiert, spielt sicherlich mit deren Empfindung, die im Ursprung vermutlich pragmatisch motiviert war. Die Wertlosigkeit könnte in einem nicht überzustrapazierenden Vergleich mit *Schwund, schwinden* gesehen werden, *kleines Schweinchen*, *pigl*--immerhin beide ungeklärt.

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Argumentation und die damit  verbundene Mühe. Aber wie auch @vectory kaufe ich ohne dedizierte Belege die starke Prämisse nicht, dass es prähistorische Indikation für Anthropozentrismus bzw. "menschliche" Überlegenheit gibt. Dies ist zwar ein zeitgenössisch kaum wegzudenkendes Motiv, ist aber in seiner Ausprägung historisch ganz und gar nicht konstant. Insbesondere andere Spezies weisen diese Attitüde nicht oder deutlich anders ausgeprägt auf.

Effektiv wird hier die zu zeigende Aussage mit sich selbst belegt.

Comment: Ich muss mich korrigieren, ich hatte folgendes gelesen: "All Indo-European languages have the same words for ‘ox’, ‘sheep’, ‘goat’, ‘horse’ and **‘swine’, but not for ‘pig’** and tame birds, which had not yet been domesticated, nor for ‘donkey’, which came from the south." (Kortland, C. C. Uhlenbeck on Indo-European, Uralic and Caucasian; Hervorhebung meine). Der Unterschied ist mir nicht klar. [\*suH- ~ \*seh3u- ~ \*sewH](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/suH-) vergleicht wie auch für "wheel" Akkadisch, Alt-Babylonisch sowie Sumerisch  ...

Comment: @bitmask: Natürlich war es nicht meine Absicht, hier einen strengen Beleg zu führen. Dennoch frage ich mich, wie der Mensch zu seinem heutigen Ausmaß an (vermeintlicher) Überlegenheit über seine Umgebung gekommen sein soll, wenn nicht der Antrieb dazu über den überwiegenden Teil der Kulturgeschichte hinweg bestanden hat. Ob nun mehr oder weniger, oder ob man es "Anthropozentrismus" nennen möchte, ist meiner Meinung nach nicht so wesentlich. Als Kern meiner Argumentation wollte ich verstanden wissen: sobald die sprachlichen Mittel für Beleidigung da waren, wurden sie auch genutzt.

Comment: Angesichts von Ratten, Eseln, Affen, Schlangen und bestimmt weiteren Tieren, die zur Beleidigung bemüht werden, erscheint mir die Fokussierung auf Tiere als Beute recht willkürlich.

Comment: @userunknown: volle Zustimmung... aber die Fokussierung hat ja der Frager gesetzt.

Comment: Ich sehe beim Frager keinen Hinweis auf Beutetiere. Außerdem sehe ich auch kein Indiz dafür, dass es überhaupt um Wildschweine geht - wieso nicht um Hausschweine? Lt. Wikipedia gibt es diese seit 9000 Jahren.

Comment: Zumindest in der bairischen Umgangssprache kommt die Sau noch sehr häufig vor. Bestimmt jede fünfte Begrüßung enthält eine, nochmal so viele haben einen Hund oder eine andere »Beleidigung« vorrätig.

Comment: @userunknown: der Fragesteller hat die Fokussierung auf Schweine gesetzt. Schweine sind zum Fressen da, egal ob sie gejagt oder im Stall gehalten werden. Es mag vielleicht in der Geschichte vereinzelte Evidenz geben, dass Schweine als Apportierschweine, Reitschweine, Rennschweine, Drogensuchschweine oder Milchschweine gehalten wurden. Aber für die meisten Leute ist ein Schwein einfach nur ein Schnitzel mit Beinen dran. Ob du nun mit der Bezeichnung des Schweins als Beutetier einverstanden bist, oder nicht, interessiert - fürchte ich - kein Schwein.

Comment: Ich habe nicht die Fokussierung auf Schweine in Frage gestellt, sondern die Fokussierung auf Beutetiere. "Schweine sind zum Fressen da" mag für Dich stimmen, für Juden und Moslems stimmt es nicht, für Schweine auch nicht, aber das hat, als die Beleidigung geprägt wurde, sicher niemanden interessiert. Hund wird aber auch beleidigend eingesetzt und in unseren Breiten nicht gegessen - ob gezüchtet oder gejagt ist mir wumpe, aber Du sprichst 2x von Beutetieren und das kommt von Dir, nicht von Bitmask, also müsstest Du es erläutern und gezüchtete Nutztiere nennt man nicht Beute.

Comment: @userunknown: ich glaube du hast dich da in einem Detail verrannt. "Beutetier" ist doch nur ein Beispiel. Es geht mir letztendlich um Hierarchie. Derjenige, der in der Hierarchie (vermeintlich) weiter unten steht (egal ob Schwein, Hund, Penner, Spast oder Spongo) dient dem Beleidiger als Gleichnis für das Opfersein, und erfüllt in der Beleidigung (im Sinne von "virtuell physisches Leid zufügen") die Rolle einer Drohung und Disziplinierung: ...

Comment: ...sieh nur, wenn du weiter so schwach und planlos bleibst, wie das Schwein, als das ich dich beleidigt habe, dann endest du ebenso wie es - am Spieß (der "Ungläubigen'). Mach also lieber, was ich dir sage.

Comment: Schön, es ist ein Detail. 6x kommt "Beute" in Deinem Text vor und erst sträubst Du Dich, die Kritik anzunehmen und versuchst es auf den Frager abzuwälzen, der nicht von Beute gesprochen hat, jetzt sagst Du es war nur ein Beispiel. Beutetiere ein Beispiel für Tiere überhaupt? Zwischenzeitlich bringst Du Hunde als Fressfeinde (Konkurrenz?) ins Spiel, jetzt kommt das Am-Spieß-Enden, was für Hunde wieder nicht passt. Deine Argumentation ist eben nicht konsistent, wie schon bei Beutetieren und Mästen. Ich meine Du hast Dich verrannt.

Comment: okay, ich habe mich wohl verrannt...